# setcap cap_net_admin in linux containers prevents user access to every file

Tags: linux, docker, permissions, centos, centos7

I have a tcpdump application in a CentOS container.  I was trying to run tcpdump as nonroot.  Following this forum post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/530920/tcpdump-permissions-problem (and some other documentation that reinforced this), I tried to use setcap cap_net_admin+eip /path/to/tcpdump in the container.

After running this, I tried to run tcpdump as a different user (with permissions to tcpdump) and I got "Operation Not Permitted".  I then tried to run it as root which had previously been working and also got, "Operation Not Permitted".  After running getcap, I verified that the permissions were what they should be.  I thought it may be my specific use case so I tried running the setcap command against several other executables.  Every single executable returned "Operation Not Permitted" until I ran setcap -r /filepath.

Any ideas on how I can address this issue, or even work around it without using root to run tcpdump?

Comment: Could you provide the details: how do you run the container, how do you enter it and change the capabilities, how do you then run something that does not work, etc.?

Comment: I've got a container that runs tcpdump. I can run tcpdump (promiscuous mode) with the root account, but I can't with a non root user because the user doesn't have permissions to run a pcap (promiscuous) for the eth0 and lo adapters. The traditional way is to run setcap cap_net_admin+eip /path/to/tcpdump. This command completes, but then running tcpdump returns "operation not permitted". Running the setcap command on any executable causes them to produce the same behavior. How can root run it without this capability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NET_ADMIN capability is not included in containers by default because it could allow a container process to modify and escape any network isolation settings applied on the container. Therefore explicitly setting this permission on a binary with `setcap` is going to fail since root and every other user in the container is blocked from that capability. To run a container with this, you would need to add this capability onto the container with the command used to start your container. e.g.

```
docker run --cap-add NET_ADMIN ...
```

However, I believe all you need is NET_RAW (setcap cap_net_raw) which is included in the default capabilities. From `man capabilities`:

```
   CAP_NET_RAW
          * Use RAW and PACKET sockets;
          * bind to any address for transparent proxying.
```

Comment: Thank you!  I imagine that breaks some security functionality?  Is there a secure way to give a non-root user rights to listen on lo and eth0 (in promiscuous mode)?  Also, how is the root user capable of running tcpdumps without this option?

I appreciate the help

Comment: @olelink hopefully my edit helps. Should just be cap_net_raw for tcpdump which is why it works when you run it as root.